# Emails not dropping in webmail on one ISP connection, but dropping on another, what could cause?

Tags: email, isp, webmail

I have a peculiar situation. My ISP provides internet for a client. Client's mail is hosted on some web host (normal webmail, commercial host).

Now when client is on my ISP, they are unable to receive mails from many domains (including yahoo, gmail, ...).

On their backup ISP, they are able to receive mails from all those domains.
Whenever they switch from my ISP to backup ISP, the mails that did not drop while on my ISP all come in (on the WEBMAIL).

I am most confused about this because even on the WEBMAIL (which should be at level of Recipient's Mail  Server), the mails do not drop when on my ISP (but they are somewhere there because they drop when the ISP is switched). I thought my company network would only affect the Mail Client, not the recipient's Mail Server.

Any pointers, ideas, information on the case will be appreciated.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic (And you asked for a tool). I've changed your question so it is now on topic, hope this is OK

Comment: Could this be an issue with grey listing? Are you saying the emails never come through on your ISP? Do you get any error message, or does the sender get a bounce back?

Comment: Thank you for the edits. It's fine. Yes the mails didn't come in through my ISP, and no bounces for the senders. Was able to find the cause. Will put it i the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find the cause of this issue. It was a DNS resolution issue. My ISP's DNS server was resolving to the old IP for the domain, and so we were getting in the wrong server entering that domain name.

Using public DNS, which was resolving to the current IPs, we were able to receive mails for that domain on my ISP.